# Laravel 4 Config::get() returns null

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 and I have created a file inside app/config as follows : The file name is aws.php

```
<?php

return [


    'key' => 'xyz',
];
```

Now, from my controller I tried to access the key as follows :

```
$key = Config::get('aws.key');
```

but it returns null. How can I solve this problem ? I have googled it but have not found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$key = \Config::get('aws.key');
```

Config is not in the same namespace as class that call this facade, so You want to go to global namespace to search Config class

Comment: It still gives null.  :(

Comment: Ok, so check the path to the file one more time. Be shure it is app\config\aws.php If that is ok create file one more time, check if `dd(\Config::get('aws'));` will show something

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes the path was incorrect. It is working now.

Answer (score 6):

You can access "key" by `Config::get('aws.key');`
but need to run this command: `php artisan config:clear`